# AES Encryption PHP to NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, aes, php-7

I am in process of moving a small project from PHP to NodeJS that includes a small part of AES Encryption.

As PHP code works fine, it goes as

```
  function decysek($data, $app_key) {
    $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($data), 'AES-256-ECB', $app_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
    return $output;
  }

  function decyGetBillData($rek , $data , $decrypted_sek){
    $decrypted_rek =  openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($rek), 'AES-256-ECB', $decrypted_sek, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);

    $decrypted_data =  openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($data), 'AES-256-ECB', $decrypted_rek, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
    return $decrypted_data;
  }

  $sekdec = decysek($request['sek'], $request['appKey']);
  $data = decyGetBillData($response['rek'], $response['data'], $sekdec);

  echo json_decode($data, true);
```

The NodeJS Conversion of the same goes as follows

```
var aes256 = require("aes256");
var js_base64_1 = require("js-base64");

function decysek(data, app_key) {
    var cipher = aes256.createCipher(app_key);
    var output = cipher.decrypt(js_base64_1.Base64.decode(data));
    return output;
}
function decyGetBillData(rek, data, decrypted_sek) {
    var cipher = aes256.createCipher(decrypted_sek);
    var decrypted_rek = cipher.decrypt(js_base64_1.Base64.decode(rek));
    var cipher2 = aes256.createCipher(decrypted_rek);
    var decrypted_data = cipher2.decrypt(js_base64_1.Base64.decode(data));
    return decrypted_data;
}
var sekdec = decysek(request["sek"], request["appKey"]);
var data = decyGetBillData(response["rek"], response["data"], sekdec);
console.log(data);
```

There is Some thing wrong with NodeJS version as it fails to give me the output,
rather throws an error.

> Provided "encrypted" must decrypt to a non-empty string.

Can you figure out the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Node.js `aes256` module doesn't support your PHP encryption algorithm, AES-256-ECB. It uses AES-256-CTR for encryption, and SHA256 as a key derivation function. The IV is generated randomly, and prepended to the ciphertext.

If you want to use this module, you should be able to encrypt - decrypt your data in PHP using the functions below.

```
/**
 * Encrypts data with the supplied passphrase, using AES-256-CTR.
 * 
 * @param string $plaintext the plaintext data.
 * @param string $passphrase a passphrase/password.
 * @return string|false encrypted data: iv + ciphertext or `false` on error.
 */
function encrypt($plaintext, $passphrase) {
    $key = hash('SHA256', $passphrase, true);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $ct = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'AES-256-CTR', $key, 1, $iv);

    return base64_encode($iv.$ct);
}

/**
 * Decrypts data with the supplied passphrase, using AES-256-CTR.
 * 
 * @param string $ciphertext encrypted data.
 * @param string $passphrase a passphrase/password.
 * @return string|false plaintext data or `false` on error.
 */
function decrypt($ciphertext, $passphrase) {
    $data = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $ciphertext = substr($data, 16);
    $key = hash('SHA256', $passphrase, true);
    $iv = substr($data, 0, 16);

    return openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'AES-256-CTR', $key, 1, $iv);
}
```

The `aes256` module is using `crypto` internally, which is a built-in module and it supports AES-256-ECB. So you could still port your PHP code to JS, but I wouldn't recommend that. AES-256-ECB is a very weak encryption algorithm, and it doesn't provide authentication.

---

Both PHP7 and `crypto` support authenticated encryption algorithms, so you could use GCM for example. Also it's best to use a KDF, like PBKDF2 (which is also supported by PHP and  `crypto`) for creating the key.

PHP encryption with AES-256-GCM, PBKDF2 with SHA256:

```
/**
 * Encrypts data with the supplied passphrase, using AES-256-GCM and PBKDF2-SHA256.
 * 
 * @param string $plaintext the plaintext data.
 * @param string $passphrase a passphrase/password.
 * @return string|false encrypted data: salt + nonce + ciphertext + tag or `false` on error.
 */
function encrypt(string $plaintext, string $passphrase) {
    $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $nonce = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12);
    $key = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $passphrase, $salt, 40000, 32, true);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'aes-256-gcm', $key, 1, $nonce, $tag);

    return base64_encode($salt.$nonce.$ciphertext.$tag);
}

/**
 * Decrypts data with the supplied passphrase, using AES-256-GCM and PBKDF2-SHA256.
 * 
 * @param string $ciphertext encrypted data.
 * @param string $passphrase a passphrase/password.
 * @return string|false plaintext data or `false` on error.
 */
function decrypt(string $ciphertext, string $passphrase) {
    $input = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $salt = substr($input, 0, 16);
    $nonce = substr($input, 16, 12);
    $ciphertext = substr($input, 28, -16);
    $tag = substr($input, -16);
    $key = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $passphrase, $salt, 40000, 32, true);

    return openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'aes-256-gcm', $key, 1, $nonce, $tag);
}
```

JS encryption with AES-256-GCM, PBKDF2 with SHA256:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

/**
 * Encrypts data with the supplied passphrase, using AES-256-GCM and PBKDF2-SHA256.
 * 
 * @param {String} $plaintext the plaintext data.
 * @param {String} $passphrase a passphrase/password.
 * @return {String} encrypted data: salt + nonce + ciphertext + tag.
 */
function encrypt(plaintext, passphrase) {
    var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    var nonce = crypto.randomBytes(12);
    var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(passphrase, salt, 40000, 32, 'sha256');

    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, nonce);
    var ciphertext = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(plaintext), cipher.final()]);
    var output = Buffer.concat([salt, nonce, ciphertext, cipher.getAuthTag()]);

    return output.toString('base64');
}

/**
 * Decrypts data with the supplied passphrase, using AES-256-GCM and PBKDF2-SHA256.
 * 
 * @param {String} $ciphertext encrypted data.
 * @param {String} $passphrase a passphrase/password.
 * @return {String} plaintext data.
 */
function decrypt(ciphertext, passphrase) {
    var input = new Buffer(ciphertext, 'base64');
    var salt = input.slice(0, 16);
    var nonce = input.slice(16, 28);
    ciphertext = input.slice(28, -16);
    var tag = input.slice(-16);
    var key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(passphrase, salt, 40000, 32, 'sha256');

    var cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, nonce);
    cipher.setAuthTag(tag);
    var plaintext = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(ciphertext), cipher.final()]);

    return plaintext.toString('utf-8');
}
```

Those functions produce compatible results, so ciphertext that is created with `encrypt` in PHP can be decrypted with `decrypt` in JS, and vice versa. Of course, this is just a basic example, production code would have more features, exception handling and possibly settings for the cipher and KDF.

Comment: Can you tell what is passphrase here

Comment: @TusharKale `passphrase` is just a string, a password. I've added some coments to make it more clear.

Comment: vice versa encryption not working. 
Ex. encrypt in node js but that cipertext not work for decrypt in PHP.. In same platform working. @t.m.adam

Comment: Thank you @t.m.adam. It was typo on PHP password phrase. Thank you again for demo too.. :+1